# How to install and override Vim in Mountain Lion for +ruby +python support?

Tags: macos, terminal, open-source

I want to install and override the current vim version in Mountain Lion due to me needing +ruby & +python support. I am particularly interested in using the brew commands from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) but I haven't seen a current best practice procedure for it (or even a bundled recipe covering vim). I am open to other ways to accomplish buildig +ruby and +python into `vim`.

Comment: I haven't used this, but a nice article here seems to scratch the same itch as you mention in your post: http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/08/brew-install-vim/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install Homebrew with

```
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

It has Ruby and Python support and will effectively replace the original Vim without actually deleting it (because the Homebrew one will be in /usr/local). Follow the directions afterward about linking the GUI app to /Applications.

Answer (score 1):

Best setup I've seen yet is YADR:

https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

Uses zsh, ruby, vim, etc all nicely configured, and very customizable.

Comment: Looks like an awesome setup, but it won't help actually getting a featureful Vim installed. See my answer.

Comment: Actually, it includes an awful lot of really useful vim packages, add-ons, etc. Totally transformed my use of it.

Comment: But it won't add Ruby or Python support to a binary that doesn't include it.